# How to set data from Firestore as initialvalue to a TextField in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, textfield

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class ProfileSettings extends StatefulWidget {

 @override
 _ProfileSettingsState createState() => _ProfileSettingsState();
 
}

class _ProfileSettingsState extends State<ProfileSettings> {


 final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;

 void _setData() async{
   var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   firestoreInstance.collection("tryingdata").document(firebaseUser.uid).setData(
       {
         "name" : "john",
         "age" : 20,
         "email" : "example@example.com",
         "address" : {
           "street" : "street 24",
           "city" : "new york"
         }
       }).then((_){
     print("success!");
   });
 }



 void _updateData()async{
   var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   firestoreInstance
       .collection("tryingdata")
       .document(firebaseUser.uid)
       .updateData({"age": _age.text}).then((_) {
     print("success!");
     print(_age);
   });
 }

 final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 String userAge;
 TextEditingController _age = TextEditingController();

 void _retrieveData() async{
   var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   firestoreInstance.collection("tryingdata").document(firebaseUser.uid).get().then((value)
     => userAge = value.data["age"]);
   print(userAge);
 }

 @override

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   _retrieveData();
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text(
         "Profilepage",
         style: TextStyle(
           fontFamily: "tepeno",
           fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
         ),
       ),
       actions: <Widget>[

       ],
     ),
         body: Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           TextField(
             controller: _age,
             initialvalue: //here I need help,
             textAlign: TextAlign.left,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
               border: InputBorder.none,
               hintText: 'PLEASE ENTER YOUR AGE',
               hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
             ),
           ),
             RaisedButton(
             onPressed: () {
                     _setData();
             },
               child: const Text('SetData', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
            ),
           RaisedButton(
             onPressed: () {
              _updateData();
             },
             child: const Text('UpdateData', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
           ),
           RaisedButton(
             onPressed: () {
               _retrieveData();
             },
             child: const Text('RetrieveData', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
           ),
         ]
     ),
   );
 }

}
```

The _setData() and the _updateData() function is working fine. I want to show in the TextField the initial value. When I click on _RetrieveData() button it prints out the value for example: 20 then I update the data to 21 and when I print it out again, it's still 20. Also sometimes it prints out null. I'm running _RetrieveData() in Widget build too. So I need to get the data from firestore and set it as initialvalue in TextField, then I can update it. How can I solve this? I'm new to Flutter. Thank you!

I got some help and this is the solution:

```
Future<dynamic>_retrieveData() async{
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    await Firestore.instance.collection("tryingdata").document(firebaseUser.uid).snapshots().listen((DocumentSnapshot doc) async{
      Map<String, dynamic> document =doc.data;
      setState((){
        userAge=document['age'];
      });

    });
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _retrieveData();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use condition in widgets like this:

```
Container(child: value==null?Text('20'):Text(value))
```

Add this code to initState method

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
      _retrieveData();
    }
```

Full code would be:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class ProfileSettings extends StatefulWidget {

 @override
 _ProfileSettingsState createState() => _ProfileSettingsState();
 
}

class _ProfileSettingsState extends State<ProfileSettings> {


 final firestoreInstance = Firestore.instance;

 void _setData() async{
   var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   firestoreInstance.collection("tryingdata").document(firebaseUser.uid).setData(
       {
         "name" : "john",
         "age" : 20,
         "email" : "example@example.com",
         "address" : {
           "street" : "street 24",
           "city" : "new york"
         }
       }).then((_){
     print("success!");
   });
 }



 void _updateData()async{
   var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   firestoreInstance
       .collection("tryingdata")
       .document(firebaseUser.uid)
       .updateData({"age": _age.text}).then((_) {
     print("success!");
     print(_age);
   });
 }

 final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 String userAge;
 TextEditingController _age = TextEditingController();

 void _retrieveData() async{
   var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   firestoreInstance.collection("tryingdata").document(firebaseUser.uid).get().then((value)
     => userAge = value.data["age"]);
   print(userAge);
 }

 @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
          _retrieveData();
        }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text(
         "Profilepage",
         style: TextStyle(
           fontFamily: "tepeno",
           fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
         ),
       ),
       actions: <Widget>[

       ],
     ),
         body: Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           TextField(
             controller: _age,
             initialvalue: //here I need help,
             textAlign: TextAlign.left,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
               border: InputBorder.none,
               hintText: 'PLEASE ENTER YOUR AGE',
               hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
             ),
           ),
             RaisedButton(
             onPressed: () {
                     _setData();
             },
               child: const Text('SetData', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
            ),
           RaisedButton(
             onPressed: () {
              _updateData();
             },
             child: const Text('UpdateData', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
           ),
           RaisedButton(
             onPressed: () {
               _retrieveData();
             },
             child: const Text('RetrieveData', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
           ),
         ]
     ),
```

Comment: I go to this page from another page, where I click on a button and it redirects me here, then the value is always null.

Comment: the button works but when I first enter the page, the value is null, the _retrieveData() function runs in Widget build, this returns null, then I click on RetrieveData button and it retrieves me the right value in console.

Comment: Show me the log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220665/discussion-between-blueshit-and-amon-chowdhury).

Comment: I/flutter ( 7479): null // here I entered the page
I/flutter ( 7479): 7 //I I clicked on RetrieveData button

Comment: If It worked. Please set it as correct answer. It would be helpful for others.